# Shortest Path Algorithm with Fuel Constraint and Variable Refueling

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

Suppose you have an undirected weighted graph. You want to find the shortest path from the source to the target node while starting with some initial "fuel". The weight of each edge is equal to the amount of "fuel" that you lose going across the edge. At each node, you can have a predetermined amount of fuel added to your fuel count - this value can be 0. A node can be visited more than once, but the fuel will only be added the first time you arrive at the node. **All nodes can have different amounts of fuel to provide.

This problem could be related to a train travelling from town A to town B. Even though the two are directly connected by a simple track, there is a shortage of coal, so the train does not have enough fuel to make the trip. Instead, it must make the much shorter trip from town A to town C which is known to have enough fuel to cover the trip back to A and then onward to B. So, the shortest path would be the distance from A to C plus the distance from C to A plus the distance from A to B. We assume that fuel cost and distance is equivalent.

I have seen an example where the nodes always fill the "tank" up to its maximum capacity, but I haven't seen an algorithm that handles different amounts of refueling at different nodes. What is an efficient algorithm to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this problem is NP-hard. Given an instance of traveling salesman path from s to t with decision threshold d (Is there an st-path visiting all vertices of length at most d?), make an instance of this problem as follows. Add a new destination vertex connected to t by a very long edge. Give starting fuel d. Set the length of the new edge and the fuel at each vertex other than the destination so that (1) the total fuel at all vertices is equal to the length of the new edge (2) it is not possible to use the new edge without collecting all of the fuel. It is possible to reach the destination if and only if there is a short traveling salesman path.

Accordingly, algorithms for this problem will resemble those for TSP. Preprocess by constructing a complete graph on the source, target, and vertices with nonzero fuel. The length of each edge is equal to the distance.

If there are sufficiently few special vertices, then exponential-time (O(2^n poly(n))) dynamic programming is possible. For each pair consisting of a subset of vertices (in order of nondecreasing size) and a vertex in that subset, determine the cheapest way to visit all of the subset and end at the specified vertex. Do this efficiently by using the precomputed results for the subset minus the vertex and each possible last waypoint. There's an optimization that prunes the subsolutions that are worse than a known solution, which may help if it's not necessary to use very many waypoints.

Otherwise, the play may be integer programming. Here's one formulation, quite probably improvable. Let `x(i, e)` be a variable that is 1 if directed edge `e` is taken as the `i`th step (counting from the zeroth) else 0. Let `f(v)` be the fuel available at vertex `v`. Let `y(i)` be a variable that is the fuel in hand after `i` steps. Assume that the total number of steps is `T`.

```
minimize sum_i sum_{edges e} cost(e) x(i, e)
subject to
for each i, for each vertex v,
    sum_{edges e with head v} x(i, e) - sum_{edges e with tail v} x(i + 1, e) =
        -1 if i = 0 and v is the source
         1 if i + 1 = T and v is the target
         0 otherwise
for each vertex v, sum_i sum_{edges e with head v} x(i, e) <= 1
for each vertex v, sum_i sum_{edges e with tail v} x(i, e) <= 1
y(0) <= initial fuel
for each i,
    y(i) >= sum_{edges e} cost(e) x(i, e)
for each i, for each vertex v,
    y(i + 1) <= y(i) + sum_{edges e} (-cost(e) + f(head of e)) x(i, e)
for each i, y(i) >= 0 
for each edge e, x(e) in {0, 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no efficient algorithm for this problem.  If you take an existing graph `G` of size `n` you can give each edge a weight of 1, each node a deposit of 5, and then add a new node that you are trying to travel to connected to each node with a weight of `4 * (n -1)`.  Now the existence of a path from the source to the target node in this graph is equivalent to the existence of a Hamiltonian path in `G`, which is a known np-complete problem.  (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path for details.)

That said, you can do better than a naive recursive solution for most graphs.  First do a breadth first search from the target node so that every node's distance to the target is known.  Now you can borrow the main idea of Dijkstra's A* search.  Do a search of all paths from the source, using a priority queue to always try to grow a path whose current distance + the minimum to the target is at a minimum.  And to reduce work you probably also want to discard all paths that have returned to a node that they have previously visited, except with lower fuel.  (This will avoid silly paths that travel around loops back and forth as fuel runs out.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the fuel consumption as positive weight and the option to add the fuel as negative weight and additionally treating the initial fuel available as another negative weighted edge, you can use [Bellman Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) to solve it as single source shortest path.

As per [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24768/shortest-path-in-weightedpositive-or-negative-undirected-graph), elsewhere, undirected graphs can be addressed by replacing each edge with two in both directions. The only constraint I'm not sure about is the part where you can only refuel once. This may be naturally addressed, by the the algorithm, but I'm not sure.